# JavaScript Undefined madness

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof, classname

```
var requestInfo;
var requestParent;

var switchButton = setInterval( function() {
  requestParent = document.getElementsByClassName("solid_color_2");
  if(typeof requestParent[0] != "undefined") {
   requestInfo = requestParent[0].getElementsByTagName('A');
   requestInfo[0].className = "";
   requestInfo[0].className = "instance-0";
   requestParent[0].className = "";
   requestParent[0].className = "button";
   requestInfo[0].style.backgroundColor = "#029c53";
   clearInterval(switchButton);
   console.log("interval last time");
  }
}, 1000);
```

> Can't execute "requestParent[0].className = "button";

here's markup:

```
<div class="button solid_color_2">
  <a class="primary-color instance-0" href="#">REQUEST INFO</a>
</div>
```

Here's error:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a *live* node list, which means that changes in the DOM for are reflected by changes in the list.

So, with this line you're getting a live node list of button elements

```
requestParent = document.getElementsByClassName("solid_color_2");
```

But then with this line...

```
requestParent[0].className = "";
```

you're clearing the classname *removing that element from the list* causing the error when you try to update it.

Your best option is to use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a HTML collection that is *not* live. You can remove the lines that set `className = ""` too.

```
var switchButton = setInterval( function() {

  // pay particular attention here because we're picking up
  // a element using it's *class*, hence .solid_color_2 and
  // not solid_color_2 (without the preceding dot)
  requestParent = document.querySelectorAll(".solid_color_2");
  if (typeof requestParent[0] != "undefined") {
   requestInfo = requestParent[0].querySelectorAll('a');
   requestInfo[0].className = "instance-0";
   requestParent[0].className = "button";
   requestInfo[0].style.backgroundColor = "#029c53";
   clearInterval(switchButton);
   console.log("interval last time");
  }
}, 1000);
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mmseev74/3/)

Comment: This is great! Being able to remove the className = "" is like a bonus too! Now going to use setInterval more often knowing I can do this .. Interesting how you pass the .className to the querySelectorAll method .. reminds me of this little thing called jQuery..

Comment: If you find this answer useful don't forget to click the tick next to it @JonathanJames